# VSCode Remote-Containers connect error ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

This used to work, but now it no longer does. Same results on two separate laptops (Both Windows 10 1809, running latest version of VSCode 1.40.1 and Docker 19.03.5)

Whenever I attempt to connect to a Remote-Container
I get an error message box `An error occurred setting up the container.`
Console shows:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888
        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1054:14)
```

Trying the steps here replicates the issue:
https://code.visualstudio.com/remote-tutorials/containers/getting-started

I also tried the go and python containers found here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers and I get the same results.

The same result occurs both when opening vscode from the folder and selecting "Reopen in Container" or from vscode running Remote-Containers: Attach to Running Container...

Here is the full console log from opening the node container when following the [Getting Started](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote-tutorials/containers/getting-started) tutorial:

```
Setting up container for folder or workspace: t:\vscode-remote\vscode-remote-try-node
Run: docker build -f t:\vscode-remote\vscode-remote-try-node\.devcontainer\Dockerfile -t vsc-vscode-remote-try-node-3a7df3aafed499f89916e2d733a210d4 t:\vscode-remote\vscode-remote-try-node\.devcontainer
Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.632kB
Step 1/6 : FROM node:10
10: Pulling from library/node
844c33c7e6ea: Pulling fs layer
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [>                                                  ]  110.2kB/10.8MB
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [=>                                                 ]  228.5kB/10.8MB
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [=>                                                 ]  343.2kB/10.8MB                                                           f8427fdf4292: Downloading [=>                                                 ] 844c33c7e6ea: Downloading [>                                                  ]  465.6kB/45.38MB                                                                ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [=>                                                 ]  343.2kB/10.8MB
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [==>                                                ] 
 457.9kB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [====>                                              ] 
ada5d61ae65d:
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [==>                                                ] 
 572.6kB/10.8MB
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [===>                                               ] 
 687.3kB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [=====>                                             ] 
844c33c7e6ea: Downloading [=>                                                 ] 
 920.3kB/45.38MB
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [===>                                               ] 
   802kB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [========>                                          ] 
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [====>                                              ] 
 916.7kB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [=========>                                         ] 
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [====>                                              ] 
844c33c7e6ea: Downloading [=>                                                 ] 
 1.383MB/45.38MB
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [====>                                              ] 
 1.031MB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [===========>                                       ] 
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [=====>                                             ] 
 1.146MB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [===========>                                       ] 

ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [=====>                                             ] 
 1.261MB/10.8MB
844c33c7e6ea: Downloading [==>                                                ] 
 1.846MB/45.38MB
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [=====>                                             ] 
 1.261MB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [=============>                                     ] 
 1.211MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting

f8427fdf4292: Downloading [=============>                                     ]  1.211MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [======>                                            ]  1.375MB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [==============>                                    ]  1.256MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [======>                                            ]   1.49MB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [===============>                                   ]  1.363MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
844c33c7e6ea:
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [======>                                            ]   1.49MB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [================>                                  ]  1.465MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
844c33c7e6ea: Downloading [==>                                                ]  2.301MB/45.38MB
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [=======>                                           ]  1.604MB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [================>                                  ]  1.465MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting

f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [==================>                                ]  1.563MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [=======>                                           ]  1.719MB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [==================>                                ]  1.563MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [==================>                                ]  1.621MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
844c33c7e6ea: Downloading [===>                                               ]  2.759MB/45.38MB

f8427fdf4292: Downloading [==================>                                ]  1.621MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
44594f2195cd: Waiting
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [========>                                          ]  1.834MB/10.8MB

f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [====================>                              ]   1.76MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [=========>                                         ]  1.948MB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [====================>                              ]  1.805MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
844c33c7e6ea: Downloading [===>                                               ]  3.226MB/45.38MB
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [=========>                                         ]  1.948MB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [====================>                              ]  1.805MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [======================>                            ]   1.94MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [==========>                                        ]  2.178MB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [======================>                            ]   1.94MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting

f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
844c33c7e6ea: Downloading [====>                                              ]  3.681MB/45.38MB
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [==========>                                        ]  2.178MB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [========================>                          ]  2.088MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [========================>                          ]  2.133MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [==========>                                        ]  2.292MB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [========================>                          ]  2.133MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [=========================>                         ]  2.178MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting

f8427fdf4292: Downloading [=========================>                         ]  2.178MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
844c33c7e6ea: Downloading [====>                                              ]   4.14MB/45.38MB
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [===========>                                       ]  2.407MB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [==========================>                        ]  2.317MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [===========>                                       ]  2.522MB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [===========================>                       ]  2.411MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
844c33c7e6ea: Downloading [=====>                                             ]  4.607MB/45.38MB
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [===========>                                       ]  2.522MB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [===========================>                       ]  2.411MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [=============================>                     ]  2.555MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [============>                                      ]  2.751MB/10.8MB

f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [=============================>                     ]  2.604MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
844c33c7e6ea: Downloading [=====>                                             ]  5.065MB/45.38MB
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [============>                                      ]  2.751MB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [===============================>                   ]  2.747MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [=============>                                     ]  2.981MB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [===============================>                   ]  2.747MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [================================>                  ]  2.796MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [==============>                                    ]  3.095MB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [================================>                  ]  2.796MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [=================================>                 ]  2.903MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
844c33c7e6ea: Downloading [======>                                            ]  5.524MB/45.38MB
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [==============>                                    ]  3.095MB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [=================================>                 ]  2.948MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
9b4289f800f5: Waiting
9b8b4aee1f5f: Waiting
ada5d61ae65d: Downloading [==============>                                    ]  3.218MB/10.8MB
f8427fdf4292: Downloading [=================================>                 ]  2.948MB/4.34MB
f025bafc4ab8: Waiting
7a9577c07934: Waiting
844c33c7e6ea: Pull complete
ada5d61ae65d: Pull complete
f8427fdf4292: Pull complete
f025bafc4ab8: Pull complete
7a9577c07934: Pull complete
9b4289f800f5: Pull complete
9b8b4aee1f5f: Pull complete
44594f2195cd: Pull complete
b0d47c2d812b: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:1ded328ae22686db9107eaa0e786fb8161e67531bfcfea635a39ae3be0b39904
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:10
 ---> d5680e53a228
Step 2/6 : ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
 ---> Running in 2b2727930c62
Removing intermediate container 2b2727930c62
 ---> ec7c46184e17
Step 3/6 : ARG USER_UID=1000
 ---> Running in 9c3f5461efce
Removing intermediate container 9c3f5461efce
 ---> f4ff2e51ee47
Step 4/6 : ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID
 ---> Running in 164d2c863412
Removing intermediate container 164d2c863412
 ---> 5dd1f70add68
Step 5/6 : RUN apt-get update     && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends apt-utils dialog 2>&1     && apt-get install -y git procps     && rm -rf /opt/yarn-*     && rm -f /usr/local/bin/yarn     && rm -f /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg     && apt-get install -y curl apt-transport-https lsb-release     && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/$(lsb_release -is | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - 2>/dev/null     && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/$(lsb_release -is | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends yarn     && npm install -g eslint     && if [ "$USER_GID" != "1000" ]; then groupmod node --gid $USER_GID; fi     && if [ "$USER_UID" != "1000" ]; then usermod --uid $USER_UID node; fi     && apt-get install -y sudo     && echo node ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/node     && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/node     && apt-get autoremove -y     && apt-get
 clean -y     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Running in 60a600d38c99
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [91.0 kB]
Get:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release [118 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release.gpg [2365 B]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages [27.9 kB]
Get:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [508 kB]
Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages [7086 kB]
Fetched 7927 kB in 3s (2247 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libapt-inst2.0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-utils dialog libapt-inst2.0
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 865 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2744 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 libapt-inst2.0 amd64 1.4.9 [192 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 apt-utils amd64 1.4.9 [410 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 dialog amd64 1.3-20160828-2 [262 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 865 kB in 0s (4410 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libapt-inst2.0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 29962 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libapt-inst2.0_1.4.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapt-inst2.0:amd64 (1.4.9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apt-utils.
Preparing to unpack .../apt-utils_1.4.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apt-utils (1.4.9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dialog.
Preparing to unpack .../dialog_1.3-20160828-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dialog (1.3-20160828-2) ...
Setting up libapt-inst2.0:amd64 (1.4.9) ...
Setting up dialog (1.3-20160828-2) ...
Setting up apt-utils (1.4.9) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u4) ...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
git is already the newest version (1:2.11.0-3+deb9u4).
procps is already the newest version (2:3.3.12-3+deb9u1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
curl is already the newest version (7.52.1-5+deb9u9).
Suggested packages:
  lsb
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-transport-https distro-info-data lsb-release
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 204 kB of archives.
After this operation, 322 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 apt-transport-https amd64 1.4.9 [171 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 distro-info-data all 0.36 [5810 B]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 lsb-release all 9.20161125 [27.1 kB]
Fetched 204 kB in 0s (1212 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package apt-transport-https.
(Reading database ... 30247 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apt-transport-https_1.4.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apt-transport-https (1.4.9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package distro-info-data.
Preparing to unpack .../distro-info-data_0.36_all.deb ...
Unpacking distro-info-data (0.36) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lsb-release.
Preparing to unpack .../lsb-release_9.20161125_all.deb ...
Unpacking lsb-release (9.20161125) ...
Setting up apt-transport-https (1.4.9) ...
Setting up distro-info-data (0.36) ...
Setting up lsb-release (9.20161125) ...
OK
deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Get:5 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease [17.1 kB]
Get:7 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable/main all Packages [9122 B]
Get:8 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable/main amd64 Packages [9122 B]
Fetched 35.3 kB in 0s (57.1 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Recommended packages:
  nodejs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  yarn
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 890 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5399 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable/main amd64 yarn all 1.19.1-1 [890 kB]
Fetched 890 kB in 0s (3536 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package yarn.
(Reading database ... 30271 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/yarn_1.19.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking yarn (1.19.1-1) ...
Setting up yarn (1.19.1-1) ...
/usr/local/bin/eslint -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js
+ eslint@6.7.0
added 123 packages from 83 contributors in 10.473s
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  sudo
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1054 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3106 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 sudo amd64 1.8.19p1-2.1+deb9u1 [1054 kB]
Fetched 1054 kB in 0s (4379 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package sudo.
(Reading database ... 30289 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../sudo_1.8.19p1-2.1+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking sudo (1.8.19p1-2.1+deb9u1) ...
Setting up sudo (1.8.19p1-2.1+deb9u1) ...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Removing intermediate container 60a600d38c99
 ---> 6646e6b71921
Step 6/6 : ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=
 ---> Running in f75175dea422
Removing intermediate container f75175dea422
 ---> 0ee68124bcb4
Successfully built 0ee68124bcb4
Successfully tagged vsc-vscode-remote-try-node-3a7df3aafed499f89916e2d733a210d4:latest
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
Run: docker run -a STDOUT -a STDERR -p 127.0.0.1:3000:3000 --mount type=bind,source=t:/vscode-remote/vscode-remote-try-node,target=/workspaces/vscode-remote-try-node,consistency=consistent -l vsch.quality=stable -l vsch.remote.devPort=0 -l vsch.local.folder=t:\vscode-remote\vscode-remote-try-node -u node --entrypoint /bin/sh vsc-vscode-remote-try-node-3a7df3aafed499f89916e2d733a210d4 -c echo Container started ;  while sleep 1; do :; done
Container started
Run: docker exec febb7d23b36f3a5087d712c6ca0fc864dbadbcf4fd37b9b0f4ab135e4813caaf /bin/sh -c (cat /etc/os-release || cat /usr/lib/os-release) 2>/dev/null
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
VERSION_CODENAME=stretch
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
Run: docker cp febb7d23b36f3a5087d712c6ca0fc864dbadbcf4fd37b9b0f4ab135e4813caaf:/etc/passwd -
Forking shutdown monitor: c:\Users\tolga\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.83.1\dist\shutdownMonitorProcess \\.\pipe\vscode-remote-containers-67797b1f7842ccb4aeee933272558c868603b8c8-sock singleContainer no-trace
Run: docker exec febb7d23b36f3a5087d712c6ca0fc864dbadbcf4fd37b9b0f4ab135e4813caaf test -d /home/node/.vscode-server
Run: docker exec febb7d23b36f3a5087d712c6ca0fc864dbadbcf4fd37b9b0f4ab135e4813caaf test -d /home/node/.vscode-remote
Run: docker exec febb7d23b36f3a5087d712c6ca0fc864dbadbcf4fd37b9b0f4ab135e4813caaf /bin/sh -c set -o noclobber ; mkdir -p '/home/node/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && { > '/home/node/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.writeMachineSettingsMarker' ; } 2> /dev/null
Run: docker exec -w /home/node febb7d23b36f3a5087d712c6ca0fc864dbadbcf4fd37b9b0f4ab135e4813caaf /bin/sh -c mkdir -p '/home/node/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && cat >'/home/node/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json' <<json
                        {
                                "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"
                                                                              }
                                                                               json
Run: docker exec febb7d23b36f3a5087d712c6ca0fc864dbadbcf4fd37b9b0f4ab135e4813caaf /bin/sh -c set -o noclobber ; mkdir -p '/home/node/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && { > '/home/node/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.copyGitConfigMarker' ; } 2> /dev/null
Run: docker exec febb7d23b36f3a5087d712c6ca0fc864dbadbcf4fd37b9b0f4ab135e4813caaf test -e /home/node/.gitconfig
Run: docker cp C:\Users\tolga\.gitconfig febb7d23b36f3a5087d712c6ca0fc864dbadbcf4fd37b9b0f4ab135e4813caaf:/home/node/.gitconfig --follow-link
Run: docker exec -w /home/node -u root febb7d23b36f3a5087d712c6ca0fc864dbadbcf4fd37b9b0f4ab135e4813caaf chown node:1000 /home/node/.gitconfig
Run: docker exec febb7d23b36f3a5087d712c6ca0fc864dbadbcf4fd37b9b0f4ab135e4813caaf test -d /home/node/.vscode-server/bin/8795a9889db74563ddd43eb0a897a2384129a619
Installing VS Code Server for commit 8795a9889db74563ddd43eb0a897a2384129a619
Run: docker exec febb7d23b36f3a5087d712c6ca0fc864dbadbcf4fd37b9b0f4ab135e4813caaf mkdir -p /home/node/.vscode-server/bin/8795a9889db74563ddd43eb0a897a2384129a619_1574537099111
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888
        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1054:14)
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was the local Fiddler Proxy I had setup at one point that was no longer running.

Problem disappeared after removing the Http Proxy setting from VSCode:

> File => Preferences => Settings

Search for "proxy" and remove any setting for `Http: Proxy`. Alternatively correct the issue with the Proxy. In my case I could have just started Fiddler.

Comment: Lifesaver, so many times does the default capture traffic setting catch me out!